# Python IMAP lib: unset \Seen flag after moving email

Tags: python, imap

I use `imaplib` to connect to a mailserver. Then I fetch emails using:

```py
status, messages = imap.select("INBOX")
emails_queue = []
for i in range(int(messages), 1, -1):
  res, msg = imap.fetch(i, "(FLAGS RFC822 UID)")
  emails_queue.append(msg)
```

Then I parse/process/decode the emails in `emails_queue`. Finally, I loop over all emails in the queue to run spam detection checks, and if some check outputs true, I run the following method:

```py
  def spam(imap, uid, spam_folder="INBOX.spam"):
    # Undo Thunderbird flag
    imap.uid('STORE', uid, '-FLAGS', 'NonJunk')

    # Move to spam folder
    result = imap.uid('COPY', uid, spam_folder)

    if result[0] == "OK":
      # Mark for deletion by expunge()
      result = imap.uid('STORE', uid, '+FLAGS', '(\\Deleted)')
```

The problem I'm having is that the newly-moved spam emails are then automatically set to "read" (with `\Seen` flag), which is not convenient because the filter output needs to be manually checked once in a while.

But I don't see how to manually unset the `\Seen` flag on the copied email, since it lives in another mailbox where it has another UID. The UID part can be dealt with by querying the `Message-ID` from headers, but I understand this will need to `select` the spam folder, which would break the current mail loop over the INBOX.

I have the same problem with only flagging emails, they all get `\Seen` afterwards.

Is there a way to prevent clever things from happening when the `COPY` or `+FLAG` commands are run ?

Comment: Fetching RFC822 is setting the seen flag.  Fetch BODY.PEEK[] instead.

Comment: try https://github.com/ikvk/imap_tools

Comment: @Vladimir fetching `BODY.PEEK[]` solved it, I'm not looking for another third-party piece of bloatware.

Comment: @AurélienPierre, This bloatware are with open sourсe code and downloads 70000 time in month ;-) I didn't mean to offend you.